# Using long division on polynomials

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Can anyone show me how to find $x^5 + 1$ divided by $x^3 + 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
          x^2
        +----------
x^3 + 1 | x^5 + 1
          x^5 + x^2
         -----------
          -x^2 + 1
```

If you *really* must have everything line up, you could do

```
                1
        +---------------
1 0 0 1 | 1 0 0 0 0 1
          1 0 0 1 0 0
         -------------
               -1 0 1
```

where I've omitted the actual monomials and just wrote the coefficients in order to save space (you don't have to omit them; I'm just lazy). This might be more useful when your polynomials aren't missing so many terms.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x^5 + 1 = x^2(x^3+1) + (1-x^2)$. Note that $1-x^2$ cannot be divided by $x^3+1$ anymore since it has lower degree. It follows that $x^5+1$ gives $x^2$ when divided by $x^3+1$, with remainder $1-x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $x^5+1$ as $x^5+0x^4+0x^3+0x^2+0x+1$ so that you have places for all the powers. Then proceed like you would with regular number long division making sure to keep the appropriate places lined up. Note that for this particular problem some of these extra places end up not being used. When you are first learning polynomial long division, it is easier to see how this works with all the places there. As you get better, you can start leaving them out or skipping steps.